# Fire e.force:closeQuickAction from lwc wrapped in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quickaction

I've wanted to re-use my lwc quick action on another object, but turns out it's not supported. Hence I'm wrapping my lwc in aura component.

I want to close the modal via button press. Was hopping I could just fire the event from lwc, without doing additional wrapping.

Naively tried this, but no luck:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('e.force:closeQuickAction'));
```

Got error

```
Invalid event type "e.force:closeQuickAction" dispatched in element <c-my-modal>. Event name must start with a lowercase letter and followed only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it:-

1. The lwc can be directly used with quick action, check [this](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/editRecordScreenAction). To close the quick action panel, you can use [CloseActionScreenEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-lwc-quick-actions) of 'lightning/actions' adaptor.

minimal required piece of code:-

```
    import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
    handleCancel() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
```

2. You can wrap lwc in aura and [fire an event from lwc that can be listened in Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components)  and event handler will fire close quick action event.